# Difference between Android Studio different views

Tags: android, android-studio

I have recently started using Android studio and observed the different views available at top left corner with options like (Project, Packages, Android, Scratches) .
I was searching for it but didn't get significance of each and difference between them.
Can anyone help me for this?

[image: Screen shot of the drop down]

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

From [this](http://developer.android.com/tools/studio/index.html), it says:

The **Project view** structure appears different than you may be used to in Eclipse but considered as traditional.

The **Android project view** shows a hierarchy that helps you work with Android projects by providing a flattened structure that highlights the most commonly used files while developing Android applications. However, the project structure on disk differs from this representation.

To sum up:

1. Project view: traditional
2. Android view: Most commonly used files (flattened version of your project's structure that provides quick access to the key source files)
3. Package: View as package list
4. Problem: links to the source files containing any recognized coding and syntax errors
5. Project files: focus on files (provide project-wide files and settings that apply across all modules in the project)

Figure 1: The traditional project view (left) and the Android project view (right).[image: 1]